# Resize Screen based on Device Resolution Monogame Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, xna, monogame

I develop game using monogame framework.
code of game itself is converted from XNA code, which i coded previously before.
I develop game asset (background, etc) for 800*480 resolution. problem appear when i try run it in different device resolution (emulator 720p). 
How to resize it actually?

I already add this code, but nothing happen

```
public Game1()
{
_graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
this.Windows.ClientSizeChanged += Window_ClientSizeChanged;
}

void Window_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int currentWidth = this.Window.ClientBounds.Width;
int currentHeight = this.Windows.ClientBounds.Height;
}
```

that code only return 0 value for both currentWidth and currentHeight;

i also follow this code

```
this.Window.ClientSizeChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Window_ClientSizeChanged);

void Window_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = Window.ClientBounds.Width;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = Window.ClientBounds.Height;
graphics.ApplyChanges();
}
```

But it has similar result. Nothing happen for resize.
Please point me a way to fix this. Because my game only be able to run in 480*800 resolution. In other resolution, it will display some space instead.

Thanks before.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Making Resolution independent games, here is a blog which will give you a step by step procedure to achieve it.
http://www.craftworkgames.com/blog/monogame-code-snippets/monogame-resolution-independence/

Comment: It seems that the link is dead.

Comment: Since this doesn't summarize the link, and the link is dead, this answer is now useless.

Answer (score 0):

How I handled it for my game was, something that I think was a simple solution.

You need two things: design dimensions, and device dimensions. Sounds like you coded it for 800 * 480 so those are your design dimensions.

So you need to get the actual device width and height first. I do this in the App.xaml.cs because if you want to reuse your code for another platform (we did) you will want to do their specific way to get screen dimensions.

So in App.xaml.cs you can do this:

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get device viewport.
        double scaleFactor = (double)App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor / 100f;
        double width = App.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth * scaleFactor;
        double height = App.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight * scaleFactor;

        ResolutionSystem.SetResolutionAndScale((float)width, (float)height);
    }
```

Now what you are doing is getting the devices scale factor (with 1.0 being 800 * 480 for WP8). You then get the ActualWidth and ActualHeight (which are always 800 and 480) and then multiply by the scaling factor. So there you have your device dimensions now, and you're not wiring into the game logic itself (unless your logic needed to be based off of the possibility of a mid game landscape to portrait switch).

So then what we do is set the game's scaling Matrix. There's a lot of other stuff I had to do with scaling and render targets due to shaders and UI but I'll keep it simple. Essentially you want to now get a scaling matrix for your sprite batch that you run the gameplay on. This means you do everything in your desired design viewport bounds then scale it to the desired size after the fact (you may want to consider redoing your assets for a higher resolution like WXGA or even 1080p if you can).

So to get our scale matrix in our ResolutionSystem.cs class we call:

```
public static void SetResolutionAndScale(float deviceWidth, float deviceHeight)
    {

        ScaleMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(DeviceWidth / DesignWidth,
                                         DeviceHeight / DesignHeight,
                                         1f);
    }
```

This function for us does a lot more but I trimmed it all out. So you should now have a scale matrix for you to store however you'd like.

Now in your draw call which can be done in numerous ways you simple include that scale matrix as the Matrix transformMatrix parameter in the SpriteBatch.Begin call.

So something like this:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, null, null, null, null, null, ResolutionSystem.ScaleMatrix);
```

And you should now have something that works. You can check out my game SkyFehl in the Windows Phone Store and test it out. It was used with design parameters of 1280 * 768. Porting over to iOS was relatively easy using this method (I won't link it in case that's frowned on). Hopefully I made some form of sense.